# VIsual Basic - Scan same item

Tags: vba

How to check if textbox contains the same barcode of the previous item scaned so that if it does, i will automatically increase quantity something like this:

```
Dim nextItemBarcode As String = Me.txtBarkodi.Text
Dim quantity As Integer = 1

If Me.txtBarkodi.Text = nextItemBarcode Then
    quantity += 1
Else
    quantity = 1
End If
```

Do you think I am missing sth or could there be a better algorithm for this scenario?

Comment: This doesn't look like VBA

Comment: did you mean to tag this as Visual Basic? you set nextItemBarcode = to the value of the textbox then you test if they are equal, which will always be true. you need to get nextItemBarcode from somewhere other then the textbox that holds the last item scanned. In general you would want to store the value of the scan in the textbox, then set lastItemScanned = to the textbox value, then when a new scan occurs and is stored in the textbox compare it to lastItemScanned. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing something. :-)

You need to store the value of the **last** bar code, not the next bar code. If the new one is the same as the last, you increment the quantity. If it's not the same, you reset quantity to one and store the new bar code as the last bar code.

```
Dim lastItemBarcode As String = ""
Dim quantity As Integer

' Scan now. If this is the first bar code,
' quantity will be set to 1 in the Else branch below
' Your scan should work in a loop starting here, so
' it keeps going and doesn't reset lastItemBarcode
' or quantity
If Me.txtBarkodi.Text = lastItemBarcode Then
    ' bar code same as last. Just increase quantity
    quantity += 1
Else
    ' Either the first item scanned, or a different
    ' item. Save this bar code as the current one,
    ' and start our queantity at 1
    lastItemBarcode = me.txtBarkodi.Text
    quantity = 1
End If
```